# Should sources helping me understand concepts but not crucial to reconstruct my work be cited?

Tags: citations, ethics

For example, to calculate a specific exponent E, I need to read book A on summation, book B on multiplication, book C on exponent. After that I can do E.

- C is surely cited, but is it required A and B to be cited too? If not, should they be cited?
- If both A and A' are excellent resources to understand what's summation is, is it fine to cite both of them?
- C' is also about exponent, but C is the one actually makes me understand what the exponent is. Should C' be cited?

Comment: I would often add a bibliography section for those types of sources. Not only does it give credit where it's due, but it gives the reader sources to help _them_ understand the concepts if needed.